# How do you hang something on sheetrock if you have metal wall studs?

Tags: drywall, walls, shelving, hanging

How do you hang something on sheetrock if you have metal wall studs? The item is a very heavy shelf, so anchors aren't going to cut it.

Comment: How heavy is "very heavy"?

Comment: Hardwood wine rack, probably 20-30lbs empty. Then add some expensive liquor and vintages...

Comment: Why not a wine rack that sits on the floor like a regular shelf? Liquid is heavy, and if your wine is nice enough to belong on a rack, it is expensive. Not worth the risk in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use toggle bolts based on my experience with them and on the ratings given here: http://www.powers.com/pdfs/plastic/togglebolt.pdf.

Comment: looks like toggle bolts are the thing to use.  Here's a vid including a load test where a guy hangs his body weight off of four of them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz8xYi_5pgg

Answer (score 0):

Use heavy duty anchors spaced appropriately. If anchors will not do it, attaching to a stud will not work either and the object must be hung from a joist.